# SSRS 2016 Query bug? What am I missing?

Tags: reporting-services

When I run my query in the Query Designer, it returns the correct information.  When I run the exact same code as a report, it ignores my where clause, and my DB just pukes everything into the table/charts.  How do I make it only report what my query is asking for?

This query works through MS query, and it works in the SSRS Query Designer.  But it will not return the correct info in the Report Builder

```
SELECT q.entityid,
       i.reqnum as "Request Number",
       CASE 
         WHEN (p.work_group) IS NULL THEN (w.work_group)
         ELSE (p.work_group)
       END as "Workgroup",
       w.creator_userid    as  "Creator",
       a.store_number as "Store Number", 
       s.division  as   "Division",
       s.region  as  "Region",
       s.city  as   "City",
       s.state   as   "State",
       CASE
         WHEN CAST(a.relo_date AS INT) = 10101 THEN MONTH(a.open_date)
         ELSE MONTH(a.relo_date)
       END as "Date Occupied", 
       i.servicetyp as "Service Type", 
       i.subservtyp as "Sub Service Type",
       CASE
         WHEN (v.vdrname) IS NULL THEN (w.vendor_name)
         ELSE (v.vdrname) 
       END as "Vendor",
       i.vendinvnum as "Invoice Num",
       i.invdate as "Invoice Date",
       i.invamount as "Invoice Amount", 
       i.description as "Description", 
       i.class as "Class", 
       i.createuser as "Created By", 
       i.createdate as "Create Date",
       a.bldtype  as  "Building Type",
       a.prttype as  "Property Type" 

FROM dwdata.fminvoice i 
       LEFT JOIN dwdata.fmaccrnt a
              ON  i.storenum = a.store_number     
       LEFT JOIN dwdata.fmpohdr p 
              ON i.reqnum = p.purordnum 
       LEFT JOIN dwdata.fmvendor v 
              ON p.ordrvennum = v.vdrnum
       LEFT JOIN dwmirror.store s 
              ON s.sstrno=i.storenum
       LEFT JOIN dwdata.fmwrkord w 
              ON i.reqnum = w.wrkordnum
       LEFT JOIN dwdata.fmsrvreq q
              ON (w.service_request_number = q.service_request_number OR p.service_request_number = q.service_request_number)

WHERE a.lease_use = 'STORE' and i.invdate >= '2019-01-01'
       AND
      (i.invdate >= case
                      when cast(a.relo_date AS INT) =10101 THEN a.open_date
                      ELSE a.relo_date
                    END
       AND
       i.invdate <= case
                      when cast(a.relo_date AS INT) =10101 THEN a.open_date
                      ELSE a.relo_date
                    END + 365 days )
      AND a.entityid= q.entityid
```

I expect the WHERE clause to actually filter the results on the server before sending them over, but it is not.  I am getting everything.

****code posted. The where clause works everywhere else but the report builder.

Comment: You might think there's no point in posting the code, but look at it from an outsider's perspective.  If I came to you with a query issue, would you be able to diagnose the problem without seeing any part of the query?  You'll need to post the query so S.O. can try to decipher the problem.

Comment: adding to Steve-o169's comment, if there are any parameters being used in the query, show those too, including all their properties.

Comment: SQL Server Profiler is a handy tool to see what's **actually** going from SSRS to SQL Server.  That way you don't have to assume (and we all know how THAT word parses).

Comment: as a side note.. using a left join on a table and then using that in the where clause.. essentially turns that join into an Inner join

Comment: After looking at your query, I think it's relevant to know what the data types of each date is as you're doing some interesting things with those.  Also, I don't think `days` does what you think and it's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Steve-o169 is on to it.  Instead of

```
 i.invdate <= case
                      when cast(a.relo_date AS INT) =10101 THEN a.open_date
                      ELSE a.relo_date
                    END + 365 days )
```

try

```
 i.invdate <= case
                      when cast(a.relo_date AS INT) = 10101 
                      THEN DateAdd('D',365, a.open_date)
                      ELSE DateAdd('D',365,a.relo_date)
                    END)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017